# PowerShell to Get Disabled AD Users Still Licensed in O365

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365

I'm trying to run a report, to get all the users who are disabled in AD, but still have a license assigned in Office 365.
I've found a couple of scripts on various sites, and they work if just run within the PowerShell console, but the moment I try to export to a CSV, it loses the license assignment information.

The script I'm currently using is:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $true} | select userprincipalname,islicensed,Licenses,UsageLocation
```

This works, and shows the below

> UserPrincipalName IsLicensed  Licenses    UsageLocation
>
> -----------------                                ---------- --------                      -------------
>
> joe.bloggs@domain.com                                True
>   {tennent:ENTERPRISEPACK}    US

However, the moment I add:

```
| Export-Csv -Path C:\LicenseReport.csv
```

The report changes to:

> UserPrincipalName IsLicensed  Licenses    UsageLocation
>
> joe.bloggs@domain.com
>     TRUE    System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Online.Administration.UserLicense]  US

I've tried a number of other select properties for the license, such as

- $_.licenses.accountskuid
- @{n="Licenses
- Type";e={$_.Licenses.AccountSKUid}} $($license.AccountSKUid)

But none work. How do I get the report to export with the License details?

Comment: I have kind of got this to work, using the follwoing, which creates a datastring of results, then outputs the datastring to an output file. It's messy, and needs some cleaning up in excel, but does work. I was hoping the original way would work better. `$LogFile = "Office_365_Licenses.csv"
$datastring = Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $true} | select userprincipalname,islicensed,Licenses,UsageLocation
Out-File -FilePath $LogFile -InputObject $datastring -Encoding UTF8 -append`

Answer (score 1):

This is the command I use & it works:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | ?{$_.isLicensed-eq "TRUE"} | Select DisplayName, SignInName, @{n="LicensesType";e={$_.Licenses.AccountSKUid}} | Export-Csv -Path C:\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Be aware though, the MSOnline module is no longer developed. You should consider moving to the [AzureAD PowerShell module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0). 
Here is the syntax for that:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All 1 | ?{($_.AssignedLicenses | ?{$_.SkuId -eq $license.SkuId})} | SELECT DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, @{l="License";e={$license.SkuPartNumber}}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will look at AzureAD PS module. There must be something wrong with my console, or tenant or something, cause I get the same out from your script, as I do from Avshalom's above. I'll post below:

Comment: "DisplayName","UserPrincipalName","IsLicensed","LicensesType"
"Bloggs, Joe","joe.bloggs@domain.com","True",

Comment: Are you seeing that across all users? Are you using a PowerShell cmd window or an app? VS Code is brilliant, I recommend that btw.

Comment: Standard Windows PowerShell. I could try with the MS Exchange Management Shell

Comment: Shouldn't need that. I certainly don't have it installed. Curious. Can you add your full code to a github gist and I'll try running it. See if there's something minor amiss?

Comment: <script src="https://gist.github.com/anonymous/859dbd37ab63435c19623e36a68ea789.js"></script>

Comment: This uses select 'Licesnes' rather than {$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId} <script src="https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5bd0e1ec09f8b5148c785ab0bf74fa83.js"></script>

Comment: Looks like that's the embedded links you've pasted. I can't see the code I'm afraid

Comment: The Github script cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $true} | 
select userprincipalname,islicensed,@{N="Licenses";E={$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId}},UsageLocation
```

and that's in case you have only one license, but if you have more, you need to join them with commas so it will be a string compatible for the csv export, for example:

Change this:

```
@{N="Licenses";E={$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId}}
```

To This:

```
@{N="Licenses";E={$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -join ','}}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried running with those changes, so the full script being: `Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $true} | select userprincipalname,islicensed,@{N="Licenses";E={$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId}},UsageLocation | Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\O365Licensed_ADDisabledUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation` but that outputs the license column as blank: UserPrincipalName,IsLicensed,Licenses,UsageLocation
joe.bloggs@domain.com,True,,US

Comment: Tried both, with & without the -join, and each returns the same blank space in the CSV file.

Comment: Where was the typo? That still doesn't work if I add `| Export-Csv -Path C:\scripts\O365Licensed_ADDisabledUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation` at the end. Sure it works without the export, but then the code I was using worked until I tried to export. Have you tested with `| Export-Csv -Path C:\test.csv -NoTypeInformation` at the end? Does it work for you?

Comment: show me the results of: `Get-MsolUser -All | where {$_.isLicensed -eq $true -and $_.BlockCredential -eq $true} | select userprincipalname,islicensed,@{N="Licenses";E={$_.Licenses.AccountSkuId -join ','}},UsageLocation -Last 1`

Comment: Here is a screen shot: [link](http://i155.photobucket.com/albums/s317/bjblackmore/PS-Output1_2.jpg)